# Double integral changing the limits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This integral does not evaluate:

```
Integrate[
  Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2) ), {c, 0, 1}], 
 {b, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

However, reversing the integrals order yields a result:

```
Integrate[
  Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2) ), {b, -Infinity, Infinity}], 
 {c, 0, 1}]
```

Are these equivalent? Is it incorrect to use the result of the second integral when I actually need the first?

I tried specifying the assumptions (`a,b,c` reals), but that did not change anything.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)#Basic_theorems

Comment: @belisarius thank you very much! I was actually looking at that very exact page before posting here. I was just surprised that mathematica could not handle these integrals, so I doubted the assumption about the equality of these integrals

Comment: In this case you don't get a different result, but no result at all in the first case.   If you pick a value for `a` and use `NIntegrate` on the outer integral for the first case you can show that you get the same answer, ie. they are equivalent, mathematica just cant do it in the one order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: version 10.0.1 on a Mac produces the same behavior.

An extended comment and observation.

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

The double integral evaluates only with integration over c as the outer integral

```
int1 = Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)),
  {c, 0, 1}, {b, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image]

Investigating the version 10 integration over a region

With the region defined by

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= c <= 1 && -Infinity < b < Infinity,
   {b, c}];
```

Neither of these integrals evaluate

```
Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)),
 Element[{b, c}, region]]
```

returns unevaluated

[image]

```
Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)),
 Element[{c, b}, region]]
```

also unevaluated

[image]

However, interchanging the variables in the definition of the region

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= c <= 1 && -Infinity < b < Infinity,
   {c, b}];
```

Integrating as follows gives the same result as the double integral, int1

```
int2 = Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)),
  Element[{c, b}, region]]
```

[image]

```
int1 == int2
```

> True

Whereas, interchanging the order of region variables in `Element` evaluates with a different result

```
int3 = Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)),
  Element[{b, c}, region]]
```

[image]

The results from integrating over a region appear unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

In version 13 on Windows 10

```
Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)), {c, 0, 1}, {b, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > -Infinity]
```

> `1/2 \[Pi] (Erf[1 - a] + Erf[a])`

Another iterated integration

```
Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)), {b, -Infinity, Infinity}, {c, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> a > -Infinity]
```

> `Integrate[1/2 E^(-(1/2) (a - b)^2) Sqrt[\[Pi]/ 2] (-Erf[(-2 + a + b)/Sqrt[2]] +  Erf[(a + b)/Sqrt[2]]), {b, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},  Assumptions -> a > -\[Infinity]]`

returns the result of the first integration. Such behavior is quite common for iterated integrals. It is clear the double integral exists for each real value of `a`. Numeric integrations confirm `1/2 \[Pi] (Erf[1 - a] + Erf[a])`, e.g.

```
1/2 \[Pi] (Erf[1 - a] + Erf[a]) /. a -> 0.5
```

> `1.6352`

The same value is produced by

```
NIntegrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)) /. a -> 0.5, {b, -Infinity,Infinity}, {c, 0, 1}]
```

and

```
NIntegrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2)) /. a -> 0.5, {c, 0, 1}, {b, -Infinity,  Infinity}]
```

Comment: The same for complex values of `a`.